# Is it possible to change the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-host

I have a sub-domain `ABC.mydomain.com` whose `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` I would like to change to another domain `anotherdomain.com`. `Anotherdomain.com` is one that I own too. Is it possible to globally change this variable `($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` using `.htaccess`? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably isn't the most convenient solution (not sure if there is a way to do this straight through .htaccess), but I would try this:

```
# .htaccess
php_value auto_prepend_file alter_host.php

# alter_host.php
<?php
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'anotherdomain.com';
?>
```

It caused some issues with me through the Laravel framework, but it worked with a simple site..so I'd give it a go.

Comment: You're incredible, thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the $_SERVER variable using .htaccess, as you can read there http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html.
I think your real need is to redirect the page to a new domain.
Try adding this line in you .htaccess file:

Redirect 301 ABC.mydomain.com http://example.com/newdirectory/